# Polar chart not filling correctly when setting plt.ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to set the ylim of several polar charts I've been working on. The issue is that when I change `plt.ylim` inside the function, the fill and lines that connect the interior shape of the polar chart become disconnected. I can't work out why this is. I've attached a screenshot showing this below.

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to fix this? I've inserted my function and example dataframe below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd    

def make_spider(row, title, color):

    import math

    categories = list(df)
    N = len(categories)

    angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * math.pi for n in range(N)]
    angles += angles[:1]

    ax = plt.subplot(1, 5, row+1, polar=True)

    plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=8)

    values = df.iloc[row].values.flatten().tolist()
    values += values[:1]

    ax.plot(angles, values, color=color, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid')
    ax.fill(angles, values, color=color, alpha = .4)

    # here is the problematic line of code
    plt.ylim(-.3, .4)

my_dpi = 40

plt.figure(figsize=(1000/my_dpi, 1000/my_dpi), dpi=96)

my_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap('Set2', len(df.index)+1)

for row in range(0, len(df.index)):
     make_spider( row  = row, title='Cluster: ' + str(row), color=my_palette(row) )
```

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"no_rooms":{"0":-0.3470532925,"1":-0.082144001,"2":-0.082144001,"3":-0.3470532925,"4":-0.3470532925},"total_area":{"0":-0.1858487321,"1":-0.1685491141,"2":-0.1632483955,"3":-0.1769700284,"4":-0.0389887094},"car_park_spaces":{"0":-0.073703681,"1":-0.073703681,"2":-0.073703681,"3":-0.073703681,"4":-0.073703681},"house_price":{"0":-0.2416123064,"1":-0.2841806825,"2":-0.259622004,"3":-0.3529449824,"4":-0.3414842657},"pop_density":{"0":-0.1271390651,"1":-0.3105853643,"2":-0.2316607937,"3":-0.3297832328,"4":-0.4599021194},"business_rate":{"0":-0.1662745006,"1":-0.1426329043,"2":-0.1577528867,"3":-0.163560133,"4":-0.1099718326},"noqual_pc":{"0":-0.0251535462,"1":-0.1540641646,"2":-0.0204666924,"3":-0.0515740013,"4":-0.0445135996},"level4qual_pc":{"0":-0.0826103951,"1":-0.1777759951,"2":-0.114263357,"3":-0.1787044751,"4":-0.2709496389},"badhealth_pc":{"0":-0.105481688,"1":-0.1760349683,"2":-0.128215043,"3":-0.1560577648,"4":-0.1760349683}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar axes have a `set_rmax()` function [see here](https://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html). Changing the `plt.ylim()` line to

```
plt.gca().set_rmax(.4)
```

solves the issue.

Comment: So how do you let `r` start at `-.3` then?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest What does a radius of -.3 *mean*?

Comment: In this particular case, no idea. In general it means that the value of `y` is `-0.3`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest It's a polar plot. There are no negative radii. I don't get it.

Comment: So maybe this problem goes much deeper. In general there are two different ways of defining negative radii and I'm currently not sure which one matplotlib uses. But the definition is probably at the heart of OP not seeing the connections.

Comment: See [MEP24](https://matplotlib.org/devel/MEP/MEP24.html). And links within. Not sure what the current status of this is. In any case I think the answer here would rather be to shift `y` by 0.3 and adapt the ticks and labels.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for opening my eyes! (1) I would not have ever thought that somebody might want to use a polar plot this way (actually I still think it's a bad way to represent negative data). (2) I didn't even notice the negative numbers in the DataFrame -- I need to work on my observational skills! (3) Your answer deserves the accept.

Comment: Concerning (1) there is a usecase in one of the issues from someone wanting to to plot an antenna response profile. I think that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the lines get "eaten up" when they are outside the axes limits. When you set `plt.ylim(-.3, .4)` there are some points in the last two charts which lie outside of this range, namely below `-0.3`. To show them you will need to set the limits to include those points. E.g.

```
plt.ylim(-.5, .4)
```

[image]

In the following, I also set the radial grid to be spaced by 0.2, to make this plot look not so crowded. Complete runnable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    


def make_spider(df, row, title, color):
    categories = list(df)
    N = len(categories)

    angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * np.pi for n in range(N)]
    angles += angles[:1]

    ax = plt.subplot(1, 5, row+1, polar=True)

    plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=8)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-.4,.5,.2))
    plt.ylim(-.5, .4)

    values = df.iloc[row].values.flatten().tolist()
    values += values[:1]

    ax.plot(angles, values, color=color, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid')
    ax.fill(angles, values, color=color, alpha = .4)



df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {"no_rooms":{"0":-0.3470532925,"1":-0.082144001,"2":-0.082144001,
                     "3":-0.3470532925,"4":-0.3470532925},
        "total_area":{"0":-0.1858487321,"1":-0.1685491141,"2":-0.1632483955,
                      "3":-0.1769700284,"4":-0.0389887094},
        "car_park_spaces":{"0":-0.073703681,"1":-0.073703681,"2":-0.073703681,
                           "3":-0.073703681,"4":-0.073703681},
        "house_price":{"0":-0.2416123064,"1":-0.2841806825,"2":-0.259622004,
                       "3":-0.3529449824,"4":-0.3414842657},
        "pop_density":{"0":-0.1271390651,"1":-0.3105853643,"2":-0.2316607937,
                       "3":-0.3297832328,"4":-0.4599021194},
        "business_rate":{"0":-0.1662745006,"1":-0.1426329043,"2":-0.1577528867,
                         "3":-0.163560133,"4":-0.1099718326},
        "noqual_pc":{"0":-0.0251535462,"1":-0.1540641646,"2":-0.0204666924,
                     "3":-0.0515740013,"4":-0.0445135996},
        "level4qual_pc":{"0":-0.0826103951,"1":-0.1777759951,"2":-0.114263357,
                         "3":-0.1787044751,"4":-0.2709496389},
        "badhealth_pc":{"0":-0.105481688,"1":-0.1760349683,"2":-0.128215043,
                        "3":-0.1560577648,"4":-0.1760349683}})

my_dpi = 40

plt.figure(figsize=(1000/my_dpi, 1000/my_dpi), dpi=96)

my_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap('Set2', len(df.index)+1)

for row in range(0, len(df.index)):
     make_spider(df, row  = row, title='Cluster: ' + str(row), color=my_palette(row) )

plt.show()
```